# How to check MSI type if its Win32 (Non .net), .Net, App Mixed(.Net and Win32) 64 bit in c#?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I want to check the type of MSI if its Win32(Non .Net), .Net, App Mixed(.Net and Win32) or 64bit. I found how to detect type of dll but not type of Windows Installer Package. I am using WiX and C#.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does an MSI even have a type? Surely it's just a payload to deliver with some prerequisites.

Comment: some MSIs run on 32bit machines only, some run on 64bit platform only. I want to check this thing. Also I want to check if the application is .net application or desktop application. Is it possible to check? if yes then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSI type is stored in the [Summary Information Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the [Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property.